# google recaptcha: should we filter for file_get_contents $_POST variables?

Tags: php, recaptcha

Hi I have a question for google recaptcha for php

I noticed the standard line for verifying recaptcha is:

`$response =file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=". $yoursecret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);`

My question is should we verify/filter/sanitize for $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?

I thought we needed to filter/verify for everything but I couldn't find any documentation on that from google. I'm concerned someone will add something else in POST and redirect the response to another site, and then do something malicious without verification/sanitizing the $_POST variables

Comment: AFAIK I don't see a reason to validate this user input in this scenario. Don't quote me in this tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap `urlencode` around anything before inserting it into a query string, if only for reliability. Alternatively, stop building up URLs by munging strings together, and leave it to the built-in function [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?' . http_build_query([
    'secret' => $yoursecret,
    'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
    'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
]);

$response = file_get_contents($url);
```

Whether there's an obvious security vulnerability or not, *always* run things through any relevant encoding. If `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` contains a character that requires encoding differently in future (e.g. `&`), then you'll avoid problems before they happen.

Comment: To tack on to this, you don't really need to sanitize the input since *you* aren't doing anything with it, you are just passing it on to Google, who's certainly going to sanitize it if necessary anyway.

Comment: okay cool thank you. So there is no way to tack on something in $_post and make `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=` a subdomain of another site right, and then have the response return positive etc. like the / or the = prevents that right. I worry an attacker could do like `https://www.google.com.malwaresite.com` and then load something bad

Comment: actually i read up on allowed characters for subdomains and apparently the / ends that attack so thank you for all your help. i have adhd a lot